# Browsing cookies during a Chrome incognito session?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, private-browsing

It seems that when in an incognito session with Google Chrome, you can't directly view the cookies, since going to the preferences, the non-incognito Chrome session is focused, and the settings page is displayed there. Naturally, none of the incognito-cookies are shown there.

Is there an easy way to take a look at the cookies set during an incognito session?

PS: I'm using OS X, if that makes a difference

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can find the cookies in the *Developer Tools*, in the *Resources* (now *Application*) tab, even in an Incognito window.

Open them with:

- <kbd>F12</kbd> on Windows
- <kbd>⌥⌘I</kbd> on OS X

[image]

Comment: is there any way to see all the cookies? Not just the ones for the current domain

Comment: Please someone answer @rob! This is the spirit of the original question.

Comment: I think you just want to open settings -> advanced settings -> Privacy -> Content Settings -> All cookies and site data...  All your cookies show up there and are searchable.

Comment: @davidparks21 Please note that "All cookies and site data..." doesn't include cookies from incognito sessions.

Comment: Note: In ***new*** Chrome, the **tab is called Application** (not resources)

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `Developer Tools` (<kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+I</kbd>)
2. Select `Application` tab.
3. Select `Cookies` in side menu.

*Works on Google Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)*

See this image:

[image: google shot]

Comment: It shows only cookies for domains related to the current tab, not **all** cookies.

Comment: @izogfif Sure, that refer to the question just access to the cookie. and my answer was be like the above answer with have  many vote up!(https://superuser.com/a/392638/199176)